# How to run mongo docker instance at specific port

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

This is how I setup a mongodb and a backend app using docker-compose. As I am running an old mongodb instance on port `27017`, I have to use another port. So this is how I setup for port `27018`.

Mongodb is running and I can connect using `mongosh`.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - /opt/mongodb/data:/data/db
  api:
    container_name: api
    image: custom-api:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mongo:27018
```

The backend application (nestJS) tries to connect to the DB:

```
const host = process.env.DB_HOST
const mongo = 'mongodb://' + host

const options = {}
const client = new MongoClient(mongo, options)

try {
  await client.connect()
  return client.db(database)
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

But running the backend gives me a connection error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.21:27018
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:292:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'mongo:27018' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I checked the mongo container and as far as can see, it is running at port `27018` and the IP address is `172.18.0.21`

```
$ docker inspect mongo

[
    {
        "Id": "8f9a6d2c36a106edbcfd84ee4bc8f3c72ce1ee13f65dc59d4f593085bb1f72f1",
        "Created": "2023-04-13T06:25:48.388105401Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mongod"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 31483,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-04-13T06:25:49.375455874Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:0850fead9327a6d88722c27116309022d78e9daf526b407a88de09762c32e620",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9a6d2c36a106edbcfd84ee4bc8f3c72ce1ee13f65dc59d4f593085bb1f72f1/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9a6d2c36a106edbcfd84ee4bc8f3c72ce1ee13f65dc59d4f593085bb1f72f1/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9a6d2c36a106edbcfd84ee4bc8f3c72ce1ee13f65dc59d4f593085bb1f72f1/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9a6d2c36a106edbcfd84ee4bc8f3c72ce1ee13f65dc59d4f593085bb1f72f1/8f9a6d2c36a106edbcfd84ee4bc8f3c72ce1ee13f65dc59d4f593085bb1f72f1-json.log",
        "Name": "/mongo",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/opt/mongodb/data:/data/db:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "NetworkMode": "root_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "27017/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "27018"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3c94b17a3042e1ddb44e3aae5738e26c6a486c60fa827210b9c231d099c49ba3-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f4fe3c9f0ebebdf05be4238d470f4e1cf47e1dcd951827f598dfefceb83f083/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b466d85cf8ecc60e7b9d843252f7a3b93e8bd42648a9293fbd21de554475293c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5efe3f538b14b3cd7e03bfa20b47e781f8ae23585d7534620086a3426b60d1fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/00b32be3ac44afe3c34d11a5cae80f32a0ad042a15b7d8a9b9ea3b2ef2f912d0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68ef703e86c29ba143e94c68bcb336ca448dfb6671c4def38fcf0fd405f39cd3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f99e7bee906d1f6ac333d704eb409ad80b5a1800f002bb604c77eab880b4d6e7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a953e99bfbe3db3d27fbf14181309e0883ded46509a45753d7238dd3e1bcef16/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a91c55b0aa1abb4959d98ac06ec579b1193e32715d93acf3057a877cad9ee13e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/090e8dd5fd41f1676d731f7421b0878019ff30e7653059f72143ab7af156452c/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3c94b17a3042e1ddb44e3aae5738e26c6a486c60fa827210b9c231d099c49ba3/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3c94b17a3042e1ddb44e3aae5738e26c6a486c60fa827210b9c231d099c49ba3/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3c94b17a3042e1ddb44e3aae5738e26c6a486c60fa827210b9c231d099c49ba3/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/mongodb/data",
                "Destination": "/data/db",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "ac914c3fb835b5c7028b58825558fc109c94e30b13938548bbe520ba736adbc0",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ac914c3fb835b5c7028b58825558fc109c94e30b13938548bbe520ba736adbc0/_data",
                "Destination": "/data/configdb",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "8f9a6d2c36a1",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "27017/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.1",
                "MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org",
                "MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org",
                "MONGO_MAJOR=6.0",
                "MONGO_VERSION=6.0.3",
                "HOME=/data/db"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mongod"
            ],
            "Image": "mongo:6.0.3",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data/configdb": {},
                "/data/db": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "1bb0f4e8831b78bb570c3e7231260fc01cedafaedf4a8eb29808ce3c1590d21e",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "root",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "mongo",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "80b5cd3f3b8cfed3fe015e886113ba4542962190a4b7ae05029f778d3ec579c7",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "27017/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "27018"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/80b5cd3f3b8c",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "root_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "mongo",
                        "8f9a6d2c36a1"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "d6b6cc90deda1a99ae078573468d434f589225a578f12a1cd867e969054ad09d",
                    "EndpointID": "ffac6eccb9cad4692030f0b2649b5be032ed9e0003f22628fb498d5592ce6add",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.21",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:15",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I don't see the mistake in the configuration. Why is there a connection error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to access your mongodb instance from a container started within the same docker-compose.yml it's still port 27017 with your setup.

To use port 27018 you should add

```
  command: --port 27018
```

to the mongo service definition.

Then the published ports will be '27018:27018'. However, if you don't need to access mongodb from outside (mongosh or UI), you can leave out published ports at all. You might even keep 27017 internally then.

Comment: I thought the internal port could stay default and is exposed to 27018. That's why I did `27018:27017`.

Comment: Yes, the internal port can stay 27017. And you can publish the internal port on another port (in your case 27018) on the Host.

Comment: Since DB_HOST refers to "mongo", this is an "internal" connection that only works with 27017.

Answer (score 0):

Is depends where the backend application is running.

Your mongo db is available on 2 locations:

1. On the host on port 27018
2. On the Mongo container on host 'mongo' on port 27017.

#### Backend is running on the Host

In this case the backend application needs to connect to 127.0.0.1:27018.

#### Backend is running in another container.

This container is called 'api' in your docker-compose file

In this case the backend needs to connect to 'mongo:27017'.